# How can I populate JavaScript variables from an XML file?

Tags: javascript, xml, variables, automation, adobe-indesign

I am working on an automated publishing flow that populates InDesign templates using XML data. The workflow is triggered when an XML file is added to a watch folder.

In order to identify the correct InDesign template to use, I need to pull a few key data points into the JavaScript executed by InDesign.

For example, if the  element at the beginning of the XML file contains "CO" (for Colorado), I want top set a JS region variable to be "CO" and then use that variable to determine where the data is sent.

> EDITED: Updated with actual XML

So if the XML looks like:

```
<Root xmlns="kpPDCommon" xmlns:kpdc="kpPDCommon">
    <region kpdc:regionCD="CO">CO</region>
    <lob kpdc:lobCD="MCAR">Medicare</lob>
    <serviceArea kpdc:saCD="DB">Denver Metropolitan Service Area</serviceArea>
    <saPlans>
        <planName>Senior Advantage (HMO)</planName>
        <planName>Senior Advantage Medicare Medicaid (HMO D-SNP)</planName>
        <planName>Senior Advantage (HMO-POS)</planName>
    </saPlans>
...
```

I want to use that to in my JS file:

```
var RGN = region;
var VER = version;
```

These variables are then used to select the appropriate InDesign template to import the XML into.

I am new to JavaScript and would appreciate as much guidance as possible.

However, please note that the script in question must be a JSX script run by Adobe InDesign. It will NOT be run in a browser. InDesign is a fully scriptable application that runs JSX scripts either on startup or on-demand when run from its scripts panel. This script will be used as a part of an automated publishing workflow within InDesign.

I reviewed the following options but have not been able to find a solution:

1. https://bytes.com/topic/xml/answers/694987-passing-xml-element-data-javascript-asp-va , I need to populate a JS variable for InDesign and an xsl will not do what I want
2. https://medium.com/frontendweb/how-to-read-local-json-file-in-react-js-564125235fc7 , I am working with large data files and only want to pull variable data from the beginning of the file.
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUCQgqc4K2A , Same as #2, also, I would need to load a LOCAL xml file.
4. https://50linesofco.de/post/2019-07-05-reading-local-files-with-javascript, again, I am working with very large, deeply nested, data files.

I also tried the following:

```html
import("C:/Users/O146962/OneDrive - Kaiser Permanente/Desktop/Indesign Automation POC/Data/CO_DNB_Providers_Test_BR4.xml").then(response => {
    return response.text();
}).then(xmlString => {
 const xmlDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
 const region = xmlDocument.querySelectorAll("region");
 for (const region of region) {
    const code = region.textContent;
 }
 console.log();
});
```

But so far this has not worked either, since it will not load a local file.

To be clear, I do NOT want to load or import the entire xml file! I want to pull in a couple of variables defined at the start of the document.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. 
Also read 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) 
and
[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166/18157)

Comment: The built-in DOM parser in JavaScript can be used to process XML.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solution? Does it work for you?

Comment: @YuriKhristich I posted in the Adobe Forums as well and found a solution that worked: [Parsing XML with Namespaces](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/parsing-xml-with-namespaces/m-p/13795756#M527033). Apparently I needed to declare the file encoding.

Comment: I'm sure the file encoding has nothing to do with the problem. It's all about the ways to parse the XML elements properties. It can be done in many ways (via `::` notation, via `xpath()`, etc). If my solution works it would be nice if you accept it as well as you did it for the `xpath` solution in the Adobe Forum.

Comment: @YuriKhristich I tried out your updated solution and it works as well, so I have marked it as a solution. Thank you for your help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably something like this:

```
var folder = Folder('/Users/me/test');
var file = File(folder + '/test.xml');

file.open('r');
var xml = new XML(file.read());
file.close();

var RGN = xml.region.text();
var VER = xml.version.text();

alert('RGN: ' + RGN + ', VER: ' + VER);
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Update**

Here is the proper approach:

XML file:

```
<?xml-model href="../CO-Medicare_Combined-Structure.xsd"?>
<!DOCTYPE Root [
  <!ENTITY path "file:///C:/Users/O146962/OneDrive - Kaiser Permanente/Desktop/Indesign Automation POC/Assets/Icons/">
]>
<Root xmlns="kpPDCommon" xmlns:kpdc="kpPDCommon">
  <region kpdc:regionCD="CO">CO</region>
  <lob kpdc:lobCD="MCAR">Medicare</lob>
  <serviceArea>Denver Boulder</serviceArea>
  <planName>Senior Advantage Medicare Medicaid</planName>
</Root>
```

Code:

```
var dataPath = Folder("/Users/.../");
var file = File(dataPath + "/test.xml");

var ns = new Namespace ("kpPDCommon");

file.open("r");
var xml = new XML(file.read());
file.close();

var RGN = xml.ns::region;
var LOB = xml.ns::lob;
var SVCA = xml.ns::serviceArea;
var SVCA_PN = xml.ns::planName;

alert("RGN: " + RGN + ", LOB: " + LOB + ", SVCA_PN: " + SVCA_PN);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Yuri. I tried your suggestions but it is not working for me. All of the variables show as blank. Did I miss something? I'll post my code and what I am getting back below.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns="kpPDCommon" xmlns:kpdc="kpPDCommon">
  <region kpdc:regionCD="CO">CO</region>
  <lob kpdc:lobCD="mcare">Medicare</lob>
  <serviceArea kpdc:lobCD="DB">Denver Boulder</serviceArea>`

Comment: `var dataPath = Folder(mainFolder + "/Data/CO_DNB-XML_TEST_SPLIT");
var file = File(dataPath + '/CO_DNB_Providers_Test_1.xml');

file.open('r');
var xml = new XML(file.read());
file.close();

var RGN = xml.Root.region.text();
var LOB = xml.Root.lob.text();
var SVCA = xml.Root.serviceArea.text();
var SVCA_PN = xml.Root.planName.text();

alert('RGN: ' + RGN + ', LOB: ' + LOB + ', SVCA: ' + SVCA + ', Plan: ' + SVCA_PN);`

Comment: Try to remove the `Root` from `var RGN = xml.Root.region.text();`

Comment: That was where I started. Same results.

Comment: I'm not an expert in XMP-parsing. As far as I can see here, this InDesign's XML object has some fancy limitations. I managed to make the code work as soon as I removed `:` from the XML tags and removed any additional texts from the `<Root>` tag: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <region kpdcregionCD="CO">CO</region>
  <lob kpdclobCD="mcare">Medicare</lob>
  <serviceArea kpdclobCD="DB">Denver Boulder</serviceArea>
</Root>`. If you can't modify your XML file this way, there is another way to parse an XML in InDesign

Comment: It looks like ID has its own rules about XML namespacing. For example this XML works fine: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
  <region aid:table="cell">CO</region>
  <lob aid:tfooter="mcare">Medicare</lob>
  <serviceArea aid:pstyle="DB">Denver Boulder</serviceArea>
</Root>`

Comment: About these `aid:...` see here: https://carijansen.com/indesign-xml-reference-guide/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253610/discussion-between-benross-kp-and-yuri-khristich).

Comment: I have posted on this topic in the Adobe InDesign Forms as well: [Parsing XML with Namespaces](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/parsing-xml-with-namespaces/td-p/13793714)

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by [Loic.Aigon](https://community.adobe.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/8593784) in the Adobe Forums: [Parsing XML with Namespaces](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/parsing-xml-with-namespaces/m-p/13795756#M527033)

It seems that in order to get this to work properly, the file encoding needs to be declared.

```
var f = File (Folder.desktop+"/test.xml");
f.encoding ="UTF-8";
f.open("r");
var x = XML(f.read());
f.close();
alert(x.xpath("//kpdc:serviceArea"));
```

Comment: Please, update your question with actual XML data. Since this answer doesn't work at all with the XLM in the question. And btw the line `f.encoding...` doesn't matter in this case. It should work fine without it.

Comment: @YuriKhristich Thank you for the update! The code I linked to has been working for me, but the updated code you provided here may be better. Also, it appears you included my actual XML in your updated response.